# Riddle with bed, tree, prisoner

Tags: riddle, word

The BED and I both have C-some.
The TREE and I both have L-some.
The PRISONER and I both are B-some.
The WEBSITE and I both have P-some.
The SHIRT and I both have S-some.

What am I?

Comment: Some weird stuff comes on google when you search for "bed tree prisoner website shirt" :D

Comment: this one has my attention. is it a typo that it says "are" in the prisoner verse?

Comment: What doesn't have some?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am

> a book

The BED and me both have C-some:

> covers

The TREE and me both have L-some:

> leaves

The PRISONER and me both are B-some:

> boxed? bonded?

The WEBSITE and me both have P-some:

> pages

The SHIRT and me both have S-some:

> sleeves

Comment: I think the Prisoner and me are both *bound*

Answer (score 5):

> ans **BUG** 
>  Bed And bug in common have bed bugs
>  Tree and Bug in common have tree bugs
>  Prisoner and bug (Bug – Inmate with psychiatric or mental problems; also known as a head case by inmates.)[prison slang](http://www.writeaprisoner.com/prison-slang.aspx#B)
>  Website and Bug in common have [Web Bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug)
>  Shirt and bug in common have bug shirts, wear to get protection from insects

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but how does it tie in with the new clues from today? "C-Some", "L-some", etc?

Comment: the question has been edited yesterday,before that there were no letters like C,L,B,P,S. And i think vicky has answered it correctly.